# What is the first sign at that Lempel-Ziv-Codierung

Tags: algorithm, decoding, lzw

I know what the second and the third sign mean at <0|0|A> but what means the first?? Why is the first sigh 7 at the last group(<7|1|#>)??

[image]

With frindly wishes sniffi

Comment: Sry that the example is on german but i have it only as a picture. I hope it will help something when i translate it here: Example(Lexicon: 8 sign, preview: 4 sign) original-message: ANNA_ASS_ANANAS. My Problem now i not understand what say me the first sign in the clip (e.g.<0|0|A>) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now i understand how that work´s the first sigh is the distance in the lexicon the second is the number of sign which is copie and the third is the next sign.

Example:  <4|1|N> that means we are at the four A from left to right. The last A is the 4th sigh in the lexicon that stay for the 4 we can copie the N to because we have an A in the lexicon that is the 1 and the N stay for the next sign.